# How to set bitmap image to Button Background Image

Tags: android, grid, cell, bmp

```
gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);    
gridcell.setText("Day 1");    
URL url = new URL("http://172.16.4.29:81/pht/2013/9/18/3027_2013_9_18_12_14_56_b.JPG");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

How can I set `bitmap` bmp image to button gridcells background Image?

Comment: ain't any answer you get helpful? If you found solution please put yours..

Comment: Check out [Android ImageButton Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/).

Answer (score 16):

You can use following code to do that..

```
BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
```

then just set bitmap with below function

```
button.setBackground(bdrawable);
```

Comment: `BitmapDrawable(bitmap)` is deprecated.

Comment: ImageButton#setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) is deprecated as well. The answer by Sruit A.Suk is better.

Comment: @n8yn8 thanks for your update.. answer edited as per requirement. :)

Answer (score 3):

you need to check current version of Android also

```
Button bProfile; // your Button
Bitmap bitmap; // your bitmap

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    bProfile.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
}
else {
    bProfile.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always and will always recommended you strongly using Image Button.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

I hope that helps you, Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

Hey First learn about Handling bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

You should not process bitmaps on the UI thread at all.
Once you have attained Bitmap use [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)'s method setImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap).

To fetch images through network, You can also use libraries like picasso, Universal Image Loader, Volley to attain what you are wanting.

Comment: he was talking about Button background, not ImageView...